# With PayPal, How to Get User To Pay Up-Front Then Bill Them "Irregularly Periodically" Without Further Approval?

Tags: c#, paypal, recurring-billing

We have a system where we require the user to pay first before we give them access to the site's features. During their first (and in fact, any) period, they could perform activities that would extend the expiration date.

Note that the Page Forwarding mechanism is OK ONLY for the first payment for the first period granted the user.

Whenever a current period expires, we would like to charge them behind the scenes FOR THE NEXT PERIOD, that is, without having them go through page-forwarding to PayPal to approve. And the subsequent charge can be different from what they were charged the first time around (due to rewards they may have earned during the period granted to them).

Billing plans and agreements seem to initially address our issue, but it seems to fit a regular billing schedule and the user doesn't get billed until the end of a regular cycle.

Note that we are working with a PayPal account, NOT a credit card number.

Comment: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/

Comment: Could you be more specific? I've been through that documentation and I can't find what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can call to request Reference Transactions be enabled on the account. Then you can have your buyers accept a billing agreement for the 1st transaction made with your company. You are able to "Reference" a transaction up to a year later (13 months is the cut off give or take a few days).

Every time you do another transaction with your buyer, update your reference Transaction ID with the most recent Transaction ID. As long as your cycles are once a year (estimated) than you should be good to go.

Here is some information for you:

https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECReferenceTxns/

I hope this gives you what you are looking for.

Comment: Is this possible with the newest PayPal SDK (C#)? It seems like we'll have to issue http calls from scratch.

Comment: I am unsure. I haven't gone into the C# SDK.